# Find the region in which the complex number lies

Tags: complex-numbers

If $|a_k|<3,n\geq k \geq 1$, then prove that all complex numbers $z$ satisfying equation $1+a_1z+a_2z^2+....+a_nz^n=0$ lie outside the circle $|z|=1/4$. This is from my multiple choice test of complex numbers is there a a way to do this in minutes

Comment: I can't solve this without putting random values of z and n and try to match the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: It's actually nothing but an application of Rouche's theorem (see this question [Finding number of roots of a polynomial in the unit disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19847/finding-number-of-roots-of-a-polynomial-in-the-unit-disk) ) for the function $g(z)=1$.

The bound is obtained via comparison with the geometric series and the answer obtained is that the claim holds.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use simple arithmetic to get, for $|z|<1$,
$$
|p(z)|\ge1-\max|a_k|(|z|+|z|^2+…+|z|^n)=1-\max|a_k|\frac{|z|(1-|z|^n)}{1-|z|}
\\
\ge\frac{1-(1+\max|a_k|)|z|}{1-|z|}
$$
So that inside the circle
$$
|z|\le\frac1{1+\max_{k=1,..,n}|a_k|}
$$
there can be no roots.

Comment: Of course.. ... studying Rouche's theorem and its applications was a waste of time after all

Comment: Often Rouche is the scalpel for individualized fine work where the hammer of the more general estimates fails.